# Rails How make a conditional inside a method on the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to make that just the user can feedback on a feedback method in the feedback model. but in the logs shows

> NoMethodError (undefined method `total_feedbacks' for nil:NilClass)

so show to make a conditional in the model?

```
def feedback_product
  user = User.find_by_id(attributes['user_id'])

  if user
    product.total_feedbacks += 1
    product.average_rating = product.feedbacks.where('buyer_feedback_date IS NOT NULL').rated(Feedback::FROM_BUYERS).average(:buyer_rating)
    product.save
  end
end
```

the feedback
`belongs_to :user`
and user
`has_many :feedbacks`

Comment: how is `product` defined? It appears to be `nil`.

Comment: max without the user conditional works

Comment: but the feedback has one product

Comment: has_one :product, through: :order

Comment: you mean you remove all calls to `product`? or just remove the `if`/`end` lines?

Comment: oh i get it now. it's defined elsewhere on the model

Comment: if i remove   if user
and end lines

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not totally clear. You didn't mention in which model this code is inside and your condition seems okay.

It seems `product` is nil, so maybe you are missing something that was not mentioned in the question, like instantiating that product. Or maybe you want your condition to be:

```
if user && product
```

Comment: Samir thank you the code is inside the feedback model
well i did not  instantiating i just grab and put there. the feedback/order related product

Comment: Besides my approach, @maxple gave you a fine set of options to solve your problem. It really depends on how you want you application to behave. If you just want to avoid this error, you either use my approach or his maxple 3rd approach.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this method assumes there is an existing product for the model in question. However if no record has been created at, then product will be nil.

This can be addressed in a few ways, which you use depends on your use-case.

1. making sure that this model creates a product upon save, e.g. through `before_save`:

   ```
   before_save :ensure_product_exists
   def ensure_product_exists
     product ||= Product.create(foo_id: self.id) # replace with correct foreign key
   end
   ```
2. making this method create the product if it does not yet exist, e.g.

   ```
   product ||= Product.new(foo_id: self.id) # replace with correct foreign key
   ```
3. making the method return early if the product does not exist, e.g.

   ```
   return unless product
   ```
4. raising an error unless the product exists

   ```
   raise(RuntimeError, "product doesn't exist") unless product
   ```

Comment: thank you. for the explanation. i'll try to use your method. grabbing a already product related to the model.

the product exists but but is related with the associated model